# openpyxl load workook only after i save workbook manually

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to remove a sheet in work book but get a Error, i notice that i have to manually open that file save it and then it load correctly.

```js
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def delete_sheet_by_name(file_path, sheet_name):
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)

    if sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[sheet_name]
        wb.remove(sheet)
        wb.save(file_path)
        print(f"The sheet '{sheet_name}' has been deleted.")
    else:
        print(f"The sheet '{sheet_name}' does not exist in the workbook.")


file_path = r'E:\Projects\Python\Delete Sheet\1.xlsx'
sheet_name_to_delete = 'Evaluation Warning'
delete_sheet_by_name(file_path, sheet_name_to_delete)
```

---

```
  File "E:\Projects\Python\Delete Sheet\pandas_solution.py", line 18, in <module>
    delete_sheet_by_name(file_path, sheet_name_to_delete)
  File "E:\Projects\Python\Delete Sheet\pandas_solution.py", line 5, in delete_sheet_by_name
    wb = load_workbook(file_path)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 301, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 237, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 465, in bind_all
    self.bind_cells()
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 368, in bind_cells
    for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 163, in parse
    obj = prop[1].from_tree(element)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Skynet\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: SheetFormatProperties.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'defaultColWidthPt'
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in whatever code/library was used to create the workbook. I'm guessing that opening it in excel causes excel to fix the issue gracefully.

Comment: I just checked your code, it works perfectly. check if your `.xlsx` file path is correct. and as the exception indicates, there might be something wrong with your Excel file format.

Comment: The error "got an unexpected keyword argument 'defaultColWidthPt'" does indicate there is a problem with the make-up of the workbook (underlying XML) most likely caused by whatever application created it. Openpyxl is unable to parse an xml file(s) however as @JNevill indicates Excel appears to be able to correct the error on opening so that it is fixed on saving. Check how the file was created.

Comment: If you have more than one affected file you may need to use a module that opens files using Excel like Xlwings or Win32com to open and save the files prior to interacting with Openpyxl. Though it should be noted if using one of the aforementioned modules to 'fix' the file, the same modules can also be used to delete sheet(s) so it would make sense to use the same module for both.

Answer (score 0):

What i want to fix format of Excel file which Microsoft Excle

```js
import openpyxl
import xlwings as xw


def fix_and_load_excel(file_path):
    try:
        app = xw.App(visible=False)  # Open Excel in the background
        workbook = app.books.open(file_path)
        workbook.save()
        workbook.close()
        app.quit()
        repaired_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

        print("Workbook repaired and loaded successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = r'E:\Projects\Python\Delete Sheet\1.xlsx'
    fix_and_load_excel(file_path)
```

can do automatically but i fond a code to do this.

Comment: But the file is corrupted so i need to fix that before opening with Openpyxl.

Comment: Yes but you dont need Openpyxl to delete a sheet, you can do that in Xlwings